# How to trap a super speedster

Tags: internal-consistency, super-powers

How would you stop a super speedster?

Things to note

Note: no future technology like forcefield.

Note: you have no superpowers.

Note:any currently available technology is fair game.

Note:you know where the speedster will be but when he will be there.

Note:You have the money to hire a team to assist you if you want.

Note: the speedster moves at speed between 700-800 miles per hour.

Deceleration: it take the speedster between 1/5 to 1/3 a second depending on how fast he is going. (I know this is unrealistic but I'm trying to make super seed practical.)

If possible keep the speedster alive, but beter to kill him then let him escape.

The speedsters body can move as fast as he runs, so his reflects are very fast.

Clarification: Someone with  superpowers speed is a speedster.

Comment: This question is fairly poorly written, and some key information (such as whether this "superhero" survives the capture or not, how much damage he can take, etc.). Also, have you considered the implications of a land-based _anything_ going 700 miles an hour? This seems like a very silly "what-if" sort of question more appropriate for XKCD

Comment: Does the speedster have to be alive after being captured?

Comment: What kind of acceleration does this guy get? If he's going 800mph then sees that there's a wall a mile away, can he change course before hitting it? And how about reflexes? Just because you *can* move fast doesn't mean you can handle it.

Comment: @JordiVilaplana I have made some changes is it any better

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I've made some changes Is It Any better?

Comment: The question is still very unclear and the lack of formatting doesn't help at all. Your question doesn't define 'speedster'. There needs to be more info here for anything approaching a reasonable answer.

Comment: @WhataTiberius I don't understand what your asking. Please clarify.

Comment: Your question assumes the reader understands the terminology of your world. What is a 'speedster'? Is it a car? A jet? A very fast amorphous blob? You keep referring to 'he' but this doesn't clarify anything beyond gender.

Comment: How quickly does this guy accelerate (not decelerate)? Is he blessed with a Speed Force _a la_ the Flash? How does he survive not being turned into liquid jelly by air resistance? How is he able to breathe at his top speed? How do his legs survive the incredible lactose buildup? How do his eyes not tear up with all the dust particles he is bound to hit in a single run? Your Flash needs a scientific basis before we can meaningfully trap him for you.

Comment: You should give more details, the usual who, why, how, where at least... otherwise any *Wile E. Coyote and The Road Runner* cartoon using products from Acme Inc.could be a fitting answer to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm oxygen? Going at such high speeds means he needs a lot of oxygen. I mean, he'd probably need massive amounts of food and water as well to keep going, but you can't really control that... If you can saturate a particular area with a bunch of chemicals that suck out oxygen, and trick the speedster into the area, you'd have a fair chance of catching him.

The chemicals used have to suck out most of the oxygen from the air. Perhaps place the chemicals (in crystal form or in huge hidden vats) in your trap area. Of course, timing is important. The chemicals can only be exposed to start working moments before the speedster arrives. Also, for obvious reasons, your team would either need to be far away (not likely) or be equipped with oxygen tanks.

Lure the speedster into the trap somehow. (Due to the lack of adequate info in the question, I can't say how to lure him. If he's a villain, put jewelry or other steal-able stuff. If he's a hero, lure him with a helpless victim or a scream for help.) Alternatively, set the trap up around his home, and activate it once he gets comfortable. Then he'll be trapped by the lack of oxygen long enough for your team to move in and put him in a cage or something. (Again, due to lack of info, not sure what kind of cage would the speedster be vulnerable to. Best bet, go with those electricity-induced laser bars things. You know, if you try to put your hand through, it'll just get sliced off...)

Yes, him being a speedster means he should be able to run out of the trap really fast. But because he's so fast, he really needs the oxygen,  or he'll also suffocate really fast. So the faster he can go, the more he'll need oxygen, and the easier it'll be to trap him this way. If you really want to take him alive, wait till he drops of oxygen deprivation, cage him, then quickly give him an oxygen mask again to resuscitate him. If not... Well, the chemicals would do your work for you...

Answer (score 3):

Well killing him could be pretty easy, if you know his path.

place 2-3 strong wires across his path, it has an extremely small surface area to see and unless his eye sight is incredible he will slice himself like cheese int chunks.  Ever been cloths-lined by a real cloths line? now replace that with a small wire and a body traveling much faster.
[image]

Otherwise to try and capture him alive, you would need something similar to aircraft carriers that is strong provides resistance but not so much as to apply lethal stopping power.

[image]

the other would be some kind of 'sticky' mousetrap, though it would need to be lots of smaller ones that stick to him messing with his ability to run.

[image]